# Unable to dismiss MFMailComposeViewController from a separate ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, email

I have a DataHandler object that shows a MFMailComposeViewController onto different ViewControllers when instantiated.

For example, in a class, I have an IBAction that emails data and calls DataHandler in order to do so:

```
@IBAction func exportData(_ sender: Any) {
    let dh = DataHandler()
    dh.sendEmail(vc: self)
}
```

DataHandler then does this:

```
func configureEmail() -> MFMailComposeViewController{
    let mailComposerVC = MFMailComposeViewController()
    let dataHandler = DataHandler()
    let data = dataHandler.getData(fileName: file!)
    mailComposerVC.mailComposeDelegate = self
    mailComposerVC.setToRecipients([emailAddr!])
    mailComposerVC.setSubject("blah!")
    mailComposerVC.addAttachmentData(data as Data, mimeType: "text/csv", fileName: "file.csv")
    return mailComposerVC
}

func sendEmail(vc: UIViewController){
    if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {
        let emailClient = configureEmail()
        vc.show(emailClient, sender: vc)
    }
    else{
        print("Unable to send emails")
    }
}
```

I'm able to send emails, however, am unable to dismiss the view controller after it's sent. I've already inserted this in DataHandler

```
func mailComposeController(_ controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MFMailComposeResult, error: Error?) {

    // Dismiss the mail compose view controller.
    controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

I have scoured the internet for solutions and am at my wits' end. Please help! :)

Edit 1:
Changed controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil) to self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

Comment: Firstly: You must present this controller.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the delegate:

```
mailComposerVC.mailComposertDelegate = self
```

Comment: Hi, I thought I did that:

mailComposerVC.mailComposeDelegate = self

Comment: Is the delegate method being called? mailComposertVC should be dismissed, but not parent vc.

Comment: Do you mean the one to dismiss the mail VC?

Comment: Yes; mailComposeController didFinishWith

Comment: I'm not sure, to be honest. I started learning Swift only recently.. I don't know how it gets called.

Comment: In Xcode you add a breakpoint, run program, and try to dismiss.

Comment: No, I don't think it's being called.

Answer (score 0):

```
func mailComposeController(_ controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MFMailComposeResult, error: Error?)
```

was defined outside of the scope of the IBAction. So the DataHandler object that was needed to dismiss the MFMailComposeViewController was not in the same scope of the dismiss function. The solution was to declare the DataHandler object as a variable of the class that was calling the DataHandler functions.